# How do I create a multilingual export?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, 8

I have Drupal 8 site which interacts with a React component.

I want to expose one of my content type's content using REST export in views.

How do I set views path to create REST export for multilingual support?

For example, mysite/rest/export/data should give JSON data in English, while mysite/nl/rest/export/data or mysite/rest/export/data/nl should give JSON data in Dutch.

Comment: As a quick fix, have you tried to create two separate views, one for EN one for NL?

Comment: @leymannx: It is not a good solution. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution in two ways.

**Method-1:**

Add language in filter criteria as mentioned below.

[image]

**Method-2:**

1) Add language in contextual filter

2) Provide a default value & select path component(I have selected 2)

3) Provide view path as `"rest/nl/export"` - EN or NL provide your language code

[image]
[image]